# How to serialize an object of type Object?

Tags: java, serialization, object

I have a class that contains an object of type `Object` (which is used as a monitor for synchronization).  Since `Object`s are not `Serializable`, what can I substitute to make serialization work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't think a field used for synchronization would need to be serialized.

Mark it `transient`.

Comment: +1, this is the only correct answer.  To Jake - an `Object` instance has no internal state; if you stop and think about it, what would you *want* to serialize about it?  The answer is inevitably "nothing", hence it should be excluded from the serialization process.

Answer (score 0):

A monitor for synchronization? Have you tried with [ReentrantLock](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)
Like Jonathon said. You should mark it as `transient`